# how to extract a number after a specific code

Tags: c#, regex

I want to extract a number from a specific code...

This is the code

```
":true,"itemId":"202190176821","defaultWatchCount":23,"isUserSignedIn":true,"isItemEnded"
```

I want to extract 23 number as programmatically.

I used regular expression and it shows nothing.

Here is the code.

```
string number = String.Empty; // default value if not found

Match m = Regex.Match(html, @"defaultWatchCount"":""([0-9]+?)");

if (m.Success)
    number = m.Groups[1].Value;
```

But it shows nothing.

Could you show me the error of my code ?

Comment: Your example string looks like JSON, if you actually do have valid JSON you should use a JSON parser.

Comment: cannot we do this using regex?

Comment: @DinithiKariyawasam yes, but if it's JSON you should use a parser instead.

Comment: You can use [`(?<="defaultWatchCount"\s*:\s*)\d+`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3d%22defaultWatchCount%22%5cs*%3a%5cs*%29%5cd%2b&i=%22%3atrue%2c%22itemId%22%3a%22202190176821%22%2c%22defaultWatchCount%22%3a23%2c%22isUserSignedIn%22%3atrue%2c%22isItemEnded%22) - no need for capture group

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use variable length lookbehinds in [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23), so the following regex should work for you regardless of whitespace in surrounding the colon `:` character. This method also doesn't require using a capture group:

[See regex in use here](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C%3D%22defaultWatchCount%22%5Cs%2A%3A%5Cs%2A%29%5Cd%2B&i=%22%3Atrue%2C%22itemId%22%3A%22202190176821%22%2C%22defaultWatchCount%22%3A23%2C%22isUserSignedIn%22%3Atrue%2C%22isItemEnded%22)

```
(?<="defaultWatchCount"\s*:\s*)\d+
```

#### Usage

[See code in use here](https://tio.run/##bVDLTsMwELz7K6w9JRCiJkg8WiqQqh4q0Qst9NKLSbapJceJvDYKQv324KTQRoiR/Fivd2Z3MrrKKoNt60jqgq8@yWI5YcMoXmNj4xcsnBJm3tQGiWSlacJY7d6VzHimBBGfN6KsFbIvxj1@UmSF9cdHJXO@FFIHYZ89/ulA1nRStbAWjeZT/gTB48MUIMedcMpuhM32s8ppC7Cli7Ff4Ta/hMlfBqlrZ/t6gLE1DiMA6dtf5D4GSEdpcj9Kbm/u0gQg@pd/nF53RfRKaFay0Jgv9ICMFp5urnP0jAP902XnjRTZngfLjpOXviXubcMm7h@Qgr7H6HfYMDyVnv3oMPPuVgrjjfEDPEuNQRm/CeUwPKse2HE/sLb9Bg)

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string pattern = @"(?<=""defaultWatchCount""\s*:\s*)\d+";
        string input = @""":true,""itemId"":""202190176821"",""defaultWatchCount"":23,""isUserSignedIn"":true,""isItemEnded""";

        foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(m.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this is a windows form application. could you edit your code please

Comment: @DinithiKariyawasam the logic is still the same. I just provided a working example. You'll have to modify it to your needs thereafter.

Answer (score 0):

Here is working regex, check it [here](https://regexr.com/3jp63):

```
Match m = Regex.Match(html, @"""defaultWatchCount"":(\d+)");
```

Your input looks like JSON, you should use JSON parser, if it really is.

Comment: @YuriyN. you forgot to escape a `"`

Comment: @ctwheels my bad, thought that @ was enough.

Comment: could you edit the answer... i tried like this and it is not working

 Match m = Regex.Match(html, @"defaultWatchCount"":""(\d+)");

Comment: @DinithiKariyawasam sure, try again, note that if you really trying `Match m = Regex.Match(html, @"defaultWatchCount"":""(\d+)")`, it's wrong, Regex must be exactly like that: `Match m = Regex.Match(html, @"""defaultWatchCount"":(\d+)");`